# AutoIt stops after one Keystroke

Tags: autoit

i need a script, that pushes a few buttons, i also got i somehow running, but i only keeps spamming like crazy

```
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>

; Press Esc to terminate script, Pause/Break to "pause"

Global $g_bPaused = False

HotKeySet("{PAUSE}", "TogglePause")
HotKeySet("{ESC}", "Terminate")
HotKeySet("{SPACE}", "ShowMessage") ; Shift-Alt-d

While 1
    Sleep(100)
WEnd

Func TogglePause()
    $g_bPaused = Not $g_bPaused
    While $g_bPaused
        Sleep(100)
        ToolTip('Script is "Paused"', 0, 0)
    WEnd
    ToolTip("")
EndFunc   ;==>TogglePause

Func Terminate()`enter code here`
    Exit
EndFunc   ;==>Terminate

Func ShowMessage()
    Send("{SPACE}p{SPACE}")
EndFunc   ;==>ShowMessage
```

What i need help with, is to write a script that does the following

-If button X is pressed, hit A,D,A fast after each other, repeat if X is pressed again.

I dont know but i couldnt find anything on google also. Please help.

Comment: how about `HotKeySet("x","EnterKeys")` and a `Function EnterKeys()` with `Send("ADA")`?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>

; Press Esc to terminate script, Pause/Break to "pause"

Global $g_bPaused = False

HotKeySet("{PAUSE}", "TogglePause")
HotKeySet("{ESC}", "Terminate")
HotKeySet("{SPACE}", "ShowMessage")
HotKeySet("x", "ADA")

While 1
    Sleep(100)
WEnd

Func TogglePause()
    $g_bPaused = Not $g_bPaused
    While $g_bPaused
        Sleep(100)
        ToolTip('Script is "Paused"', 0, 0)
    WEnd
    ToolTip("")
EndFunc   ;==>TogglePause

Func Terminate()
    Exit
EndFunc   ;==>Terminate

Func ShowMessage()
    HotKeySet("{SPACE}") ; Disable space hotkey before using space in send.
    Send("{SPACE}p{SPACE}")
    HotKeySet("{SPACE}", "ShowMessage") ; Enable space hotkey after using send.
EndFunc   ;==>ShowMessage

Func ADA()
    Send("ADA")
EndFunc
```

Change `ShowMessage` function to this modification so it
disables `{SPACE}` Hotkey, does the `Send` with spaces
and the `p`, then enables the `{SPACE}` Hotkey.

If you send the same key as the Hotkey, then the Hotkey
is triggered, which is why you need to disable it first
before sending.

The `ADA` function sends letters `ADA` if `x` is pressed.